# Structure of level sets of a noncritical point of a smooth function on a two dimensional domain

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, fluid-dynamics

Let $\psi$ be a smooth function on a two dimensional simply connected domain $\Omega$ such that $\psi=0$ on the boundary $\partial \Omega$. Suppose $\rho$ is not a critical value of $\psi$ then it is claimed that the level set $\psi= \rho$ consists of finitely many closed disjoint curves. How does one prove / see this? Also, if we were working on the two torus rather than a simply connected domain would this still be true?

Comment: Not sure what is critical value. Is it that if $\psi(x) = \rho$ than $\nabla \psi(x) \neq 0 $ ?

Comment: Simple connectivity is irrelevant, but you need more conditions at the boundary otherwise you can have infinitely many level curves accumulating at the boundary. For instance, assume $\psi$ has a smooth extension beyond the boundary and $\rho$ is still a regular value for the extended function. For proof, use implicit function thm.

Comment: This might be counter-example. There is infinitely many of them and they are not closed(as curves) https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3*+e%5E%28-x%5E2+-+y%5E2%29+%2B+cos%28+y+-+x%5E2+%29+from+-3+to+3
(does anybody know how to insert links to comment properly?)

Comment: @studiosus I think OP implicitly assumes $\rho\ne 0$ (which is necessary to make level curves closed), in which case there is no accumulation on the boundary: $\{\psi=\rho\}$ is compactly contained in $\Omega$.

Comment: @tom What is $\rho$ in your purported counterexample? To insert links, use `[text](url)` format, [like this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%2A+e%5E%28-x%5E2+-+y%5E2%29+%2B+cos%28+y+-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B+x%5E2+%29+from+-3+to+3)

Comment: @tom : Suppose there is a point x such that $\nabla \psi(x) = 0$ then a critical value $\pho= \psi(x)$.

Comment: @HowAboutaNiceBigCupof In my example is $\psi(x,y) = 3 e^{-x^2 - y^2} + \cos( y - ​ x^2 ) - 2.5 $ and $\rho$ something around $-2$.

Comment: @tom How is $\psi=0$ on the boundary $\partial \Omega$?

Comment: Doesn't [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5B+++3+E%5E%28-x%5E2+-+y%5E2%29+%2B+Cos%5By+-+x%5E2%5D+-+2.5+%3D%3D+0%2C+%7Bx%2C+-3%2C+3%7D%2C+%7By%2C+-3%2C+3%7D%5D) look like a boundary of some set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You need $\Omega$ to be bounded. Otherwise the halfplane $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x>0\}$ with $\psi (x,y)=\sin x$ and $\rho=1/2$ is a counterexample. (Infinitely many level curves, not closed)
2. You need $\rho\ne 0$. Otherwise $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:x^2+y^2<1 \}$ with $\psi (x,y)=x(1-x^2-y^2) $ and $\rho=0$ is a counterexample. (Level curve is not closed).

With the above assumptions, the statement is true, and you don't even need $\Omega$ to be simply connected. Indeed, let $M=\{(x,y)\in \Omega:\psi(x,y)=\rho\}$. This set is closed in $\Omega$ and has no limit points on $\partial \Omega$. Therefore, $M$ is compact. Since $\nabla \psi\ne 0$ on $M$, the implicit function theorem implies that $M$ is a $1$-dimensional manifold (not necessarily connected). A $1$-manifold can be covered by open sets each of which is homeomorphic to a line interval. By compactness, finitely many such sets are enough. It follows that $M$ has finitely many connected component. Each component is homeomorphic to $S^1$ by the [classification of $1$-manifolds](http://www.math.ist.utl.pt/~ggranja/TD/08/classif1manifs.pdf).

The above works just as well when $\Omega$ is a bounded open subset of a $2$-dimensional manifold (torus, etc.)

Comment: All circles with radius $n\in\mathbb{N}$ form a $1$-manifold which cannot be covered by finitely many line sections.

Comment: @tom That's why my answer contains words "bounded" and "compact".

Comment: hmm Do you take $M=\{(x,y)\in \Omega:\psi(x,y)=\rho\}$ or $M=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:\psi(x,y)=\rho\}$ ?

Comment: @tom $(x,y)\in \Omega$; edited in.

Comment: Just nitpicking, $\Omega$ needs to be closed in order to be $M$ compact.

Comment: @tom  No. Being a *domain*, $\Omega$ is open. The set $M$ is nonetheless compact.

Comment: In your counter example 2. isn't $M$ an open interval?

Comment: @tom It is. Which is why the text below the counterexamples begins with "with the above assumptions" (referring to $\Omega$ being bounded **and** $\rho\ne 0$).

Comment: @ user127096 Why cannot we have a situation where two stationary points are connected by a heteroclinic orbit?, i.e M would be homeomorphic to the closed interval [0,1]